# Authentication problem while login with Custom User Model in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-forms

I created a custom user Model, that  uses the Email field as the username.

Also I had to create a Custom backend to validate as Case Insensitive the email field.
The Registration page works perfectly fine, but when I try to login with a  user  that is not created I get this error:

```py
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/members/login/

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home',
 'projects',
 'about',
 'blog',
 'contact',
 'members',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_bleach']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/DeveloperRoad/members/backends.py", line 14, in authenticate
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get(**{case_insensitive_user_name_field: username})
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

During handling of the above exception (BlogUser matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 141, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 375, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 402, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 215, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/home/daniel/MEGA/my-git/github/Developer-Road-Website/Developer-road-website/DeveloperRoad/members/backends.py", line 17, in authenticate
    UserModel.set_password(password)

Exception Type: TypeError at /members/login/
Exception Value: set_password() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_password'
```

Here is the Custom User Model and its manager:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# Used to create the Custom User and it's manager


class BlogUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Manage the blog user, email is the login identifier and first name and last name are mandatory
    """

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        """
        Create and save an User with the given EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME and Password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Blog user must have an email address")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Blog user must have a First name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Blog user must have a Last name")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        """
        Create and save an Super User with the given EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME and Password.
        """

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


def get_profile_image_filepath(self):
    """
    Returns the profile name path to store
    """

    return f"images/profile_images/{self.pk}/profile_image.png"


def get_default_profile_image():
    """
    Returns the default profile image
    """

    return "images/default_profile_image/default.svg"


# Custom User Model

class BlogUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Basic Custom User for the Blog
    """
    username = None

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=70, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="date_joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last_login", auto_now=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath,
                                      default=get_default_profile_image, blank=True, null=True)

    hide_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = BlogUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name)

    def get_profile_image_filename(self):
        """
        Return the profile image filename
        """
        image = str(self.profile_image)
        return image[image.index(f"profile_images/{self.pk}/"):]

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

And here is the custom backend that generates the error:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class CaseModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Fix the problem of the login with insensitive email.
    """
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel =  get_user_model()
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            case_insensitive_user_name_field = f"{UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD}__iexact"
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(**{case_insensitive_user_name_field: username})

        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel.set_password(password)

        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`UserModel.set_password(password)`

to

**`UserModel().set_password(password)`**.

---

What you have done wrong is you didn't put the parenthesis. The `set_password()` is an ***instance method***, not a ***class method***